# How to access values of sub-nodes (child) with different names in XML file?

Tags: xml, r, xpath, ncbi, pubmed

I am trying to parse `xmlValue` of certain child nodes from NCBI xml file. But, for some PM.IDs, the `Root node <PubmedArticleSet>` has different information w.r.t pubmed records, `PubmedBookArticle` and `PubmedArticle`. I would like to pass a condition, `if(xmlName(fetch.pubmed) == PubmedBookArticle` extract certain values`elseif (xmlName(fetch.pubmed) == PubmedArticle` extract other values. Finally, make a `dataframe` with both the values corresponding to their PMIDs. It seems simple, but `(xmlName(fetch.pubmed)` throws error `no applicable method for 'xmlName' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument')"` Any help is appreciated, thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PubmedArticleSet PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD PubMedArticle, 1st January 2015//EN" "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/DTD/pubmed_150101.dtd">
<PubmedArticleSet>
  <PubmedBookArticle>
    <BookDocument>
      <PMID Version="1">25506969</PMID>
      <ArticleIdList>
        <ArticleId IdType="bookaccession">NBK259188</ArticleId>
      </ArticleIdList> ....

   ...... </BookDocument>
  </PubmedBookArticle>

  <PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="Publisher" Owner="NLM">
      <PMID Version="1">25013473</PMID>
      <DateCreated>
        <Year>2014</Year>
        <Month>7</Month>
        <Day>11</Day>
      </DateCreated>....

    ....</MedlineCitation>
    </PubmedArticle>
</PubmedArticleSet>
```

My code is below

```
library(XML)
library(rentrez)

PM.ID <- c("25506969"," 25032371","   24983039","24983034","24983032","24983031",
"26386083","26273372","26066373","25837167",
 "25466451","25013473")
# rentrez function to retrieve XMl file for above PIMD
fetch.pubmed <- entrez_fetch(db = "pubmed", id = PM.ID,
                             rettype = "xml", parsed = T)
# If empty records, return NA
FindNull <- function(x,x1child){
  res <- xpathSApply(x,x1child,xmlValue)
  if (length(res) == 0){
    out <- NA
  }else {
    out <- res
  }
  out
}

# extract contents from xml file
    xpathSApply(fetch.pubmed,"//PubmedArticle",FindNull,x1child = './/ArticleTitle')

    xpathSApply(fetch.pubmed,"//PubmedBookArticle",FindNull,x1child = './/BookTitle')
```

How do I get above code in a loop, so that I can retrieve values within PubmedArticle and PubmedBookArticle as an when the condition is met in each search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this, but I would maybe get separate node sets for books and articles.

```
table( xpathSApply(fetch.pubmed, "/PubmedArticleSet/*", xmlName) )
    PubmedArticle PubmedBookArticle 
                6                 6 

books <- getNodeSet(fetch.pubmed, "/PubmedArticleSet/PubmedBookArticle")

data.frame( pmid = sapply(books, function(x) xpathSApply(x, ".//PMID", xmlValue)),
           title = sapply(books, function(x) xpathSApply(x, ".//BookTitle", xmlValue))
)

      pmid                                                                                                      title
1 25506969                                                     Probe Reports from the NIH Molecular Libraries Program
2 25032371                                                       Understanding Climate’s Influence on Human Evolution
3 24983039 Assessing the Effects of the Gulf of Mexico Oil Spill on Human Health: A Summary of the June 2010 Workshop
4 24983034                                                  In the Light of Evolution: Volume IV: The Human Condition
5 24983032                                            The Role of Human Factors in Home Health Care: Workshop Summary
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. This is definitely helpful. I guess, extracting books and articles separately is more appropriate as you suggested. I tried a for loop, and it only slowed and complicated the process.

Comment: Sometimes you can search for two different names using a vector like `xpathSApply(fetch.pubmed, c("//BookTitle", "//ArticleTitle"), xmlValue)` but the first result has a BookTitle and an ArticleTitle, so its easier to work with nodes.

Comment: Or maybe `xpathSApply(fetch.pubmed, c("//BookTitle", "//Article/ArticleTitle"), xmlValue)`

Answer (score 0):

- Below NCBI XML path helps to extract `abstracts` from `PubmedArticle`, `PubmedBookArticle` and as well as those articles `without abstracts (NA)`.

  ```
  <!-- language: lang-r -->
  abstracts <- xpathSApply(fetch.pubmed, c('//PubmedArticle//Article',
           '//PubmedBookArticle//Abstract'), function(x) {
  xmlValue(xmlChildren(x)$Abstract) })
  abstracts <- data.frame(abstracts,stringsAsFactors = F)
  dim(abstracts)
  rownames(abstracts) <- PM.ID
  ```